# Maximal interval of existence of the IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be a continuous and Lipschitz  in the second variable function, and consider the IVP:

$x´=F(t,x)$

$x(t_0)=x_0$.

If $\gamma:(w^-,w^+)\to\mathbb{R}^d $ is a maximal solution of the IVP, then $(w^-,w^+)=\mathbb{R}$.

***[my achievement so far]***

I wanted to show it by contradiction, so If we assume that $w^+<\infty$, as $(t,\gamma(t))\to\partial(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ whenever $t\to w^+$, we would have $\lim_{t\to w^+}|\gamma(t)|=\infty$.

But why is this a contradiction?